# Converting DBObject to Java Object while retrieve values from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, dbobject

From my Java application, I have stored the values in mongoDB in ArrayList(set of Java objects). 
How can I retrieve the data from DBObject

I am storing the data in mongoDB like this:

```
{  "students" : [{"firstName" : "Jesse", "lastName" : "Varnell", "age" : "15", "gender" : "M" }, { "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe", "age" : "13", "gender" : "F"}] }
```

I am having the Java Object for the Student like:

```
public class Student {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String age;
    public String gender;  // M, F      
}
```

I am retrieving the data from mongoDB like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("user", username); 
DBCursor cursor = theCollection.find(query); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
    //How to get the DBObject value to ArrayList of Java Object?
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("user", username); 
DBCursor cursor = theCollection.find(query); 
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject theObj = cursor.next();
    //How to get the DBObject value to ArrayList of Java Object?

    BasicDBList studentsList = (BasicDBList) theObj.get("students");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentsList.size(); i++) {
        BasicDBObject studentObj = (BasicDBObject) studentsList.get(i);
        String firstName = studentObj.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = studentObj.getString("lastName");
        String age = studentObj.getString("age");
        String gender = studentObj.getString("gender");

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setFirstName(firstName);
        student.setLastName(lastName);
        student.setAge(age);
        student.setGender(gender);

        students.add(student);
    }               
}
```

Comment: Thanks Parvin for the response.
When I tried the above code, I got the following exception:
    
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList

Where the theObj.get("students") is in String.

Comment: Are you sure that students field in DB stores data as array? If the json object you write above is correct then this code should work. I try same code on my local and it works correctly. Most probably you students in DB as string not array.

Comment: Yes. I just copied the values from DB only. Actually, It is storing the data as Array only. It is not a string.

Comment: Can you share the full json object for single document?

Comment: This is the single document from MongoDB:

{
  "loginid" : "john.doe@mail.com",
  "streetAddress" : "4 King Farm Rd",
  "zipcode" : "17532",
  "residenceType" : "single",
  "cityState" : "Holtwood, PA",
  "phone" : "7172845772",
  "comments" : "",
  "students" : [{
      "firstName" : "Ronn",
      "lastName" : "Perkins",
      "age" : "50",
      "gender" : "M"
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Lavinia",
      "lastName" : "Perkins",
      "age" : "47",
      "gender" : "F"
    }],
  "_created" : NumberLong("1339102359831"),
  "_modified" : NumberLong("1351954577018")
}

Comment: I tried the same code with the given data on my local and it works.Check your code again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44418/discussion-between-parvin-and-vijay)

Answer (score 5):

You generally use an ORM tool for that (though it wouldn't be meaningful to call it ORM in the case of a non relational database).

There are several such tools. I like spring-data, which hides a lot of boiler plate code for you and gives you a simple, clean syntax. Something like this:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public User findsUserByUsernameAndPassword(String userName, String encodedPassword) {
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(query(where("userName").is(userName).and("encodedPassword").is(encodedPassword)), User.class);
    }
}
```

With the `User` class defined as:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    private String userName;

    private String encodedPassword;

    // snip getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Unrelated but I'm from the future (2022), we called these ODM (Object Document Mapping)